# AngularJS not rendering on webpage "AngularJSDemos" Dan Wahlin

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been working on this tutorial "AngularJSDemos" Dan Wahlin link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM, but the application SPA AngularJS is not rendering on the webpage. Is there anything missing in my codes below?

The Html pages have the following codes: "Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp"> 
<head>
     <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <!--Placeholder for views-->
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
        })
        .when('/view2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
    });

    demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', function () {
        var customers = [
            { name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix' },
            { name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'San Francisco' },
            { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' },
            { name: 'Mike Leski', city: 'Clarksburg' },

        ];

        var factory = {};
        factory.getCustomers = function() {
            return customers;
        };

        factory.postCustomer = function (customer) {

        };
        return factory;
    });

    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
        $scope.customers = [];

        init();

        function init() {
            $scope.addCustomer = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
        }

        $scope.addCustomer = function () {
            $scope.customers.push(
                {
                    name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                    city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                });
        };
    });

</script>
```

The View1.html

```
  <div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase}} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>

<br />
Customer Name:<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
<br />
Customer City:<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
<br />
<button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
<br />
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
 </div>
```

And the last one View2.html

```
  <div class="container">
  <h2>View 2</h2>
  City:
  <br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="city" />
  <br />
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase}} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the `ngRoute` dependency when you declare your demoApp module:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4u4nmn?p=preview) is the working example of your code

Also remember to add the script of ngRoute, you can use:

`npm install angular-route --save-dev`

Or add the CDN script:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js for example

**PD:** I recommend you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is more robust